# More presentable style class range values, faster

Tags: qgis, style, classification

This is as much feature suggestion as it is question:

Is there a better way to generate attractive/presentable style class ranges? Currently I have 5 similar datasets. Lets say the values for the first range from 0 to 35.39839437 and the other four from 0 to between 10 and 20, again with long trains of decimals after them.

I want to output all 5 on the same colour & number scale with one legend, so lets say 36 classes of size 1, i.e. 0-1, 1-2, ... 34-35,35-36. For equal interval breaks (the closest option) QGis will divide the range (0-35.39etc) by the number of classes so that the bins are e.g 0-0.9992, 0.9992-1.9891, ..., 34.4010-35.39etc.

Presentationally this looks crap, and so one has to go through every bin manually changing the values, which takes ages (not helped by lack of keyboard assistance e.g. tabbing, autoselect all next field). And THEN manually changing all the labels to match (SURELY there could be a tick box called "match labels to values"?)

If one goes through this lengthy process, at least one can paste this format to the other 4 maps right? No, not easily in any case: one can hack the QML file to align it to the next layer's name, as per Underdark's tip [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72392/how-to-apply-the-same-style-to-different-columns).

Does anyone have any smart tips or clever workarounds for this kind of thing? Or should I raise this overall issue to the devs on hub.qgis? It feels to me that this is an oddly rough edge on what I assume most of us use as a core feature daily?

Comment: This is pretty much 'Pretty Breaks'. Don't know how I'd not seen it / realised it before!
Match labels to values, and a way to set decimal places of labels shown would still be nice though...

Comment: As far as I remember, there should already be a feature request for that.

Comment: Since you found the solution in pretty breaks, will you close the question, or will you write an answer about pretty breaks? Something should be done otherwise this thread remains in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to Underdark,

- Easily presentable ranges: use the 'Pretty Breaks' option. This will often constrain to less classes than the user specifies in order to retain regular integer classes.
- Too many decimals: mentioned [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3566) but closed, mentioned [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5963) nearly 2 years ago & pushed to 'future release - nice to have' a year ago.
- 'Match labels to values': I didn't see anything searching roadmap; will search again then raise as an issue. Edit: done [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10203).
- Better QML sharing: not seeing anything in roadmap, will search again then raise as an issue. Edit: @Underdark, do you know if the current behaviour (QML file only applicable to the field name (and layer?) it was created on) is deliberate? It seems counterintuitive to me that one would create a style so that they could ONLY use it on the layer that they've already manually just styled... and nothing else!
- Easier keyboardability for manually editing ranges & values: will raise as an issue. Edit: done [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10204).