# In QGIS, is it possible to save graduated styles to use on different columns?

Tags: qgis, style

I'm using QGIS to produce thematic maps of 9 quantities (given in 9 columns in the attribute table) which have values broadly within the same range and I would like to plot them using the same intervals using 'Graduated' style.

[image: all columns which I would like to use style on]

However, while I can save a style, it saves the column name with it. When I load the style to attempt to apply it to another column, as soon as I change the column, it resets the intervals, which is exactly what I would like it **not** to do. Is it possible to somehow keep the interval ranges while changing the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution might be to copy the style file, open it in a text editor and find and replace the column names.

Comment: Although the guidance says not to say 'thanks', I still find that I need to thank you for the answer, @underdark ! I later also found [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72392/how-to-apply-the-same-style-to-different-columns), which turns out to be the same - sorry for duplicating the question.